# Confused about last part of Nullstellensatz proof

Tags: algebraic-geometry

We've just covered the Nullstellensatz in my Algebraic Geometry course, and I went through the similar proof in Artin's Algebra. The last part which gets the required contradiction is rather confusing to me however:

> We must remember that linear combinations can involve only finitely many vectors. So we ask: Can we have a linear relation
>   $$\sum_{v=1}^k\frac{c_v}{x-\alpha_v}=0$$ where $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_k$ are distinct complex numbers, and the coefficients $c_v$ are not zero? No. Such a linear combination of formal rational functions defines a complex valued function except at the points $x=\alpha_v$. **If the linear combination were zero, the function it defines would be identically zero. But $(x-\alpha_1)^{-1}$ takes on arbitrarily large values near $\alpha_1$, while $(x-\alpha_v)^{-1}$ is bounded near $\alpha_1$ for $v=2,...,k$.** So this linear combination does not define the zero function.

The bolded part is what confuses me. Is this using a result from complex analysis (another course I'm also taking, but am behind on and don't know if we've covered something similar). Why is $(x-\alpha_v)^{-1}$ bounded near $\alpha_1$ for $v\neq 1$, and why is that relevant?

Thanks

Comment: **Simpler:** use the [Heaviside *cover up* method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_cover-up_method) (or, equivalently, multiply by $\,x-\alpha_i\,$ then evaluate at $\,x = \alpha_i\,$ to deduce $c_i = 0)\ \ $

Comment: That's pretty cool! Never thought I'd see partial fractions again after high school. Thanks for mentioning it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's go about it piece by piece. This will be an informal explanation but I hope it helps...

You are trying to prove that

$$X= \{\,f\in \mathbb{C}[x]: f(x)=\frac{1}{x-\alpha}, \text{ for some } \alpha \in \mathbb{C}\}$$

is linearly independent. That is, for any finite number of distinct $\, f_1,\ldots,f_k \in X,$
$$F(x)=\sum_{\nu=1}^k \frac{c_\nu}{x-\alpha_{\nu}}=0 \iff \forall \nu \,(c_{\nu}=0).$$

The author of your proof argues by contradiction. If not all of the $c_{\nu}$'s are zero, could $F(x)=0$ for all $x$? The answer is no. Why?

Assume that you already know that $(x-\alpha_1)^{-1}$ is unbounded "near" $\alpha_1, c_1 \neq 0$ and the $(x-\alpha_{\nu})^{-1}, \nu \neq 1$ are  bounded "near" $\alpha_1.$ Let $N_2,\ldots,N_k$ be their respective bounds.
In that case

$$\bigg\| \sum_{\nu\neq1}\frac{c_{\nu}}{x-\alpha_{\nu}}\bigg\|= C \leq \|c_2\|N_2 +\ldots+\|c_k\|N_k= K$$
for all $x$ "near" $\alpha_1$. Now, since $(x-\alpha_1)^{-1}$ is unbounded "near" $\alpha_1$ we can find some $x$ "near" $\alpha_1$ such that $$\bigg\|\frac{c_1}{x-\alpha_1}\bigg\|>K.$$

For that particular $x$ we have that $F(x)\neq 0$ since the additive inverse of a complex number has the same norm and this 2 numbers do not. Hence $F(x)$ cannot be the zero function. **QED**

**Why is $(x-\alpha_1)^{-1}$ unbounded "near" $\alpha_1$?**

Recall that for $x \in \mathbb{R}^+$,$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{x}= \infty $$

Well, 
$$\lim_{x\to\alpha_1}\|x-\alpha_1\| = 0 \implies \lim_{x\to\alpha_1}\frac{1}{\|x-\alpha_1\|}= \infty,$$

so the norm of the complex number $(x-\alpha_1)^{-1}$ tends to infinity as $x$ tends to $\alpha_1,$ hence $(x-\alpha_1)^{-1}$ is unbounded "near" $\alpha_1.$

**Why is $(x-\alpha_{\nu})^{-1}$ bounded "near" $\alpha_1, \nu \neq 1$?**

Take any $\nu \neq 1,$ then $\alpha_{\nu} \neq \alpha_1$ and hence $d_{\nu} = \|\alpha_{\nu} - \alpha_1 \| > 0.$

Now, assume $x$ is "near" $\alpha_1$ if $\|x - \alpha_1\| < \frac{d}{2}$, where $d=\min\{d_2, \ldots, d_k\}.$ So none of the $\alpha_{\nu}$'s are "near"  $\alpha_1.$

Then if $x$ is "near" $\alpha_1$, the distance between say $\alpha_\nu$ and $x,$ $\|x-\alpha_{\nu}\|>d_{\nu} - \frac{d}{2},$ hence $\|(x-\alpha_{\nu})^{-1}\| < \frac{1}{d_{\nu}- \, \frac{d}{2}}=N_{\nu},$ hence $(x-\alpha_{\nu})^{-1}$ is bounded "near" $\alpha_1, \nu \neq 1.$

Comment: Wow thanks so much, that was really comprehensive. I'll have to dwell on some details of that argument for a bit, but I think I mostly understand. Didn't expect to find that level of detail in the midst of an algebra proof.

Answer (score 1):

If $a$ and $b$ are distinct complex numbers, we need to show that $1/(x-a)$ is bounded near $b$.  Take a neighborhood of $b$ not containing $a$.  Then $|x-a|$ has a lower bound > 0 in that neighborhood (since the neighborhood does not contain $a$), so $1/|x-a|$ has an upper bound.

This is relevant to the argument because it implies that in a neighborhood of $\alpha_1$, all the $(x-\alpha_v)^{-1}$ for $v \ne 1$ are bounded near $\alpha_1$, while the remaining term $(x-\alpha_1)^{-1}$ is unbounded near $\alpha_1$. Because we have *exactly one* unbounded term near $\alpha_1$ in the sum, the sum must be unbounded near $\alpha_1$ (if there were 2 unbounded terms, they might cancel each other out to produce something bounded).  Therefore, the sum cannot be 0.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $k>1.$

Method (Ia). Suppose $c_1\ne 0.$ Let $r=(1/2)\min \{|\alpha_1-\alpha_v: 2\leq v\leq k\}.$

Let $M=\sum_{v=2}^k|c_v|\cdot (|\alpha_1-\alpha_v|-r)^{-1}.$

Then  $0<|z-\alpha_1|\leq r\implies |\sum_{v=2}^k c_v(z-\alpha_v)^{-1}|\leq \sum_{v=2}^k|c_v|\cdot |z-\alpha_v|^{-1}\leq M.$

If $0<s<r$ and $s$ is small enough then $|c_1|s^{-1}>M $ and $|\sum_{v=1}^kc_v((\alpha_1+s)-\alpha_v)^{-1}|\geq |c_1|s^{-1}-|\sum_{v=2}^kc_v((\alpha+1)-\alpha_v)^{-1}|\geq |c_1|s^{-1}-M>0.$

Method (Ib). Suppose $c_1\ne 0.$ Let $r$ be as in (Ia). Observe that $g(x)=\sum_{v=2}^kc_v(x-\alpha_v)^{-1}$ is continuous from $D=\mathbb C \backslash \{c_v: 2\leq v\leq k\}$ to $\mathbb R,$ and so also is $|g(x)|.$ So $\{|g(x)|:x\in E\}$ is compact  for any compact $E\subset D.$  A subspace of $\mathbb C$  or of $\mathbb R$ is compact iff it is closed and bounded. So $\{|g(x)|: |x-\alpha_1|\leq r\}$ is bounded, so $a$ $fortiori,$ $\{|g(x)|: 0<|x-\alpha_1|\leq r\}$ is bounded.

But  $\{|c_1(x-\alpha_1)^{-1}|: 0<|x-\alpha_1|\leq r\}$ is unbounded. So it is not possible for $g(x)+c_1(x-\alpha_1)^{-1}$ to be uniformly $0$ on $\{x: 0<|x-\alpha_1|\leq r\}.$

Method (II). (Algebraic).  For brevity let $S=\{1,2,...,k\}$ and $T=\{\alpha_v:v\in S\}.$ Suppose $\sum_{v\in S}c_v(x-\alpha_v)^{-1}=0$ for all $x\in \mathbb C$ \ $T.$

For   $x\in \mathbb C$ let  $P(x) =\sum_{v\in S}(\; c_v\prod_{v\ne j\in S}(x-\alpha_j)\;).$

The polynomial $P(x)$ has infinitely many zeroes, because $P(x)=0$ for all $x\in \mathbb C$ \ $T.$ Therefore $P(x)=0$ for all $x\in \mathbb C.$

For $v\in S$ we have $0=P(\alpha_v)=c_v\prod_{v\ne j\in S}(\alpha_v-\alpha_j),$ and $0\ne \prod_{v\ne j\in S}(\alpha_v-\alpha_j).$